# CSS overflow hidden not working in chrome when parent has border radius and child has animation

Tags: google-chrome, animation, overflow, css

**live demo:** http://codepen.io/flanker/pen/ajAow

There are three elements like:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

In the first one parent has a `border-radius` and child element will be overflowed. In the second one parent has a `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` so the child is clipped. Both of them work fine.

But in the third one, the parent element has `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden`. This time I added a `animation` to the child element, then the `overflow: hidden` is not working in Chrome (Version 28.0.1500.52 beta / Mac OS X 10.8.3). The child is still be visible out of the parent element.

But it works fine in Firefox (20.0)

Is this a Chrome bug? Or am I missing any other CSS properties?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

All you have to do is add to the parent element follow css:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: trivial, intuitive solution

Comment: Note that the latest version of Chrome only accepts `backface-visibility: hidden;`, so non-prefixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to your last class?

```
.flash .bar {
  -webkit-animation: flash 5s linear infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The live demo is updated with this and appears to be working in chrome.

Comment: Wow so quick and it works. But I thought `overflow` specifies what happens if content overflows. Cannot understand why `overflow: hidden` in child element fix this. Also there isn't any problem in Firefox.

Comment: no problem, I just used what you already had. Firefox on my machine doesn't animate 3rd element but chrome does?!

Comment: looks like 'overflow: hidden' dose not work when I add a rotate transform to the bar. check it here: http://codepen.io/flanker/pen/yjsxn (broken in Chrome, works in Firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is fixed in Chrome 29 (Tested in Chrome Version 29.0.1547.22 beta).

Comment: This problem seems to have returned in Chrome 40

Comment: Can't reproduce this with Chrome 55